# Making a Div Positioned on an Image Responsive?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I have a div with a header and some text inside a container that contains an img used as a background where the div is positioned towards the middle/left of the image. I'm able to get everything lined up on the full display but can't seem to make it responsive. Right now the img scales fine but the div with the text doesn't: the text box stays but the text overflows. The page is otherwise responsive and I've tried everything I can in my limited repertoire.

Have tried changing position, overflow, width and height, etc.

HTML:

```
  <div class="welcome">
    <img src="pictures/hello.jpg" class="welcome-image">
    <div class="information">
        <h1>Welcome Message</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do 
           eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
           Eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Magna fermentum 
           iaculis eu non diam id volus. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.welcome{
   position: relative;
 }

.welcome-image{
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: relative;
}

.information{ 
   position: absolute;
   top: 35%;
   left: 20%;
   color: black;
   background-color: white;
   width: 50%;
   height: 55%;
   padding: 5% 5%;
   text-align: center;
}

.information h1{
   font-size: 50px;
   margin-top: 0;
}

.information p{
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you apply property of:

```
 max-width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

For better responsive experience, you can easily change css attribute depends on different resolutions.

I would suggest you to try these following codes;

```
/* For Mobile */
@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
    .information h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

/* For Tablets */
@media screen and (min-width: 540px) and (max-width: 780px) {
    .information h1 {
        font-size: 40px;
    }
}
```

For better experiences, you can change resolutions and amount of different resolutions easily.

Also, if you want to stop the wrapping the h1, you can use the following code;

```
.information h1 {
   white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I did have some of that in the CSS, this combined with another comment gave me the hint I needed to get it to position correctly when the media screen shrank. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the position:absolute from .information

Comment: This one gave me the hint I needed. I changed it to relative when media screen is smaller and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best breakpoints recommended by Bootstrap. You can set font size according to your need.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {
    .information h1 {
        font-size: 15px;
    }
}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
    .information h1 {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .information h1 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {
    .information h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {
    .information h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }
}
```